# Filter only elements that matches a regex in Athena

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-athena, presto

I have a column in a table which is of string type and the column is `,` separated.

```
Sample Input: 'ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV'
Expected output: ['ASEIAW,TPOIBV'] - An array with all matching elements which is an alphabet in upper case with exactly 6 charterers.
```

What I tried;

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT('ASEIOW,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2' , '(\b[A-Z]{6,6}\b)+');
Output: ASEIOW

select REGEXP_LIKE('ASEIOW,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2' , '(\b[A-Z]{6,6}\b)+');
Output: [v]

select REGEXP_SPLIT('ASEIOW,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2' , '(\b[A-Z]{6,6}\b)+');
Output: ['',',',',',',2']
```

Using NOT in front of regex

```
select REGEXP_SPLIT('ASEIOW,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2' , '^(\b[A-Z]{6,6}\b)+');
Output: ['',',ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2']

select REGEXP_REPLACE('ASEIOW,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2' , '^(\b[A-Z]{6,6}\b)+');
Output: ,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` with a bit simplified regex:

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('ASEIOW,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2' , '\b([A-Z]{6})\b');
```

The `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` function will extract all occurrences of the pattern matches and `\b([A-Z]{6})\b` just matches six letters enclosed with word boundaries, no need to specify the identical `min` and `max` values in range quantifiers. Nor do you need to additionally quantify the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract_all):

```sql
select regexp_extract_all('ASEIOW,ASDWQB,TPOIBV,2', '\b([A-Z]{6})\b');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [ASEIOW, ASDWQB, TPOIBV] |

Answer (score 0):

Good day. U can use nested regexp_replace like this.

```
SELECT sentences,REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(sentences,'.[[:lower:]0-9]'),'^','['''),'$',''']') as result
          FROM  
           (   
            SELECT 'ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' AS sentences from dual
            )
```